# .NET Core 5 MVC Pagination With Custom Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm in the middle of development for my third year college project, for this project I decided to use .NET Core 5 MVC which I’m not really familiar with.
I usually use razor pages but for an important project like that I wanted to use the industry standard.
Anyway, I created most of the stuff for the project but when it came to pagination I found a problem.

This is the code for the controller action, where I used a class to get the parameters from the query link (added a lot of filters that's why I used a class).

```
[Route("/Catalogue")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AllProducts([FromQuery] ProductParameters parameters,int pagenum=1)
{
    parameters.PageNumber = pagenum;
    ViewData["BrandId"] = new SelectList(await brandsrepo.GetBrandsList(), "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(await categoryrepo.GetCategoryList(), "Id", "Name");
    var viewmodel = new AllProductsViewModel { Products = await productrepo.GetProductsList(parameters), Parameters = new() };
    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

I tried to use what I know from razor pages where I use `asp-route-{param_name}="{value}"`.
But when I search and try to go to the next page all the query parameters (filters and search terms etc ) are gone and it goes only to the second page.

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item @(Model.Products.HasPrevious?"":"disabled")">
            <a class="page-link" asp-route-pagenum="@(Model.Products.PageNumber-1)">&laquo; Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item @(Model.Products.HasNext?"":"disabled")">
            <a class="page-link" asp-route-pagenum="@(Model.Products.PageNumber+1)">Next &raquo;</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I hope I can find a way to do the pagination as well as keep the parameters that were already there.
I have a last resort that is using razor components which I have used a lot in this project for reusable components.

Comment: Create the view properties you need in your controller... bind them on get.  Then you can use those routes (asp-route-propertyName) in the cshtml file.  For razor pages you don't need to return a view.  Just bind your model (view).  Or return "Page()"

Comment: So declare [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] for GETs... for search strings be sure to check for nulls:  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
            {
                SearchString = "";
            }   On POST:  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
            {
                SearchString.Trim();  ... }

Comment: you might also find "pagedlist.mvc" useful.  It's in Visual Studio's package manager.  It provides a utility function that makes things a little easier.  (It'll add utility functions to your model.)

Comment: @mason sorry i didn't notice I'm capitalizing too much, i guess from programming too much c#.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks i saw pagedlist in the documentation and i'll give it a go, i didn't try it cause i already made a custom class called paged list that does something similar

Answer (score 0):

There will be pretty much this similar kind of problem will rise again in the process of your project.
Therefore I think the overall idea that should be enlight here is "how to keep parameters across request in asp.net MVC".

And the answer is the basic of Http Request.
You are likely have 2 obvious options is to store the parameter and anything that should survive multiple request on the server:

- By using the cache and session ID.
- By sending the parameters along with each Http Request.

And I highly recommend the second approach due to it's flexibility and simplicity.

The idea was when the server receive Http Request, pass it back to the client through ViewData or ViewBag, and then let the client attach them for the next request as you can easily implement them in the view layer.

In case you are not yet familiar with these things, i suggest [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#passing-data-to-views) as your starting point.

And now, no need to third party dependency, completely control of how you paging the result and counting all result to better describe your paging list, which even more easy if you already using EF Core.

Comment: thanks so much i'll try this and tell you the results.